Ideal way to draw complex network process diagram?

How would you redesign this so it is easier to follow along with the pathways that are interacting?

The arrow means that thing goes and binds to that other thing.
The | means it interferes with that thing.

Could you lay these out in a grid of some sort, or even a vertical list, and just link them together? Maybe you highlight one object at a time, see its connections (as you hover over it), and move around like that? Press a special key to see all interactions at once (assuming vertical list).
I just think these diagrams are almost impossible to read at this level of complexity. This is a biological cell, the Insulin Receptor Signaling Pathway (part of it at least).

Hire a graphic designer. The possible solution is too complex to answer here.

How about this one then?

Why, with what goal do users consult this graphic and is every detail needed then? How to narrow it down depends too much on the context to answer.

I am currently thinking, show one object at a time, with "interactions" in green, and "interferences" in red, then just click to drill down. Don't show the whole network at once.

You could do what you mentioned in the comments but add a "view all" button/toggle. This way users can have options on how they want to view the chart.
You then want to put a tracker on the "view all" button/toggle. If you notice a lot of users are switching to the view all mode and not switching back then you probably want to switch to the view all mode as your default.
Warning: Double check to make sure that users aren't leaving right after switching to view all mode. If they aren't leaving then its safe to assume that view all should be your default view.
